# Help id-ing creature

Tags: species-identification

I know. This is going to be extremely difficult without a picture. But bear with me here, because I haven't seen it afterwards. I hope somebody can give me a list of possibles.

I was taking a stroll down the street when I saw this creature. Maybe two feet long. It was black, with a tail about the size of the tail of a cat. It had catlike paws, which were not that big. Its face was pointy, with a reddish nose and brown eyes, with a whitish area of fur above the eyes. Ears were small and curved at the end. It was hiding in a bush, and did not seem to run away when I checked it out. When I got up, it made a sharp screech and ran away.

I'm from Kerala, South India. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, bit I think that this is more or less impossible without an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like a mongoose or a civet, which species is hard to guess there are several species of both in India, and they come in a variety of colors and sizes. In the mongooses the color can vary a lot even in the same species. One easy way to tell the difference is civets have cat like ears while mongoose have short rounded ears.

But here is a picture one at least one species of each, since their body plant does not vary much even if their color and size does.

Indian Brown Mongoose, 
[image]

Sri-Lanka Mongoose
[image]

Asian Palm Civet 
[image]

Comment: Yes! That's it! I think I saw an Asian Palm Civet.

Answer (score 0):

Indian tree shrew
[image: Indian tree shrew]
Is that the guy?

Comment: Nope, this is not it,